# Time event in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to stop the Application.OnTime  when I = 4. Please advise as to what is wrong in below code.
The code is pasted in module.

```
    Sub RunEveryTwoMinutes()
    UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption = Now
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RunEveryTwoMinutes"
    MsgBox I
    I = I + 1

    If I = 2 Then
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = " Whant is the Capital of Maharashatra"
    UserForm1.OptionButton1.Caption = " Mumbai"
    UserForm1.OptionButton2.Caption = " Delhi"
    UserForm1.OptionButton3.Caption = " Kolkotta"
    UserForm1.OptionButton4.Caption = " Karnatak"
    End If


    If I = 3 Then
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = " Whant is the Capital of Delphi"
    UserForm1.OptionButton1.Caption = " Mumbai"
    UserForm1.OptionButton2.Caption = " Delhi"
    UserForm1.OptionButton3.Caption = " Kolkotta"
    UserForm1.OptionButton4.Caption = " Karnatak"
    End If

    If I = 4 Then
    Application.OnTime Now, "RunEveryTwoMinutes", , False

    Exit Sub


    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving or what is not happening.  Explain in more detail what you are expecting, what is happening.  Also you Use the varialbe I but dont show how it is declared.

Comment: There is no loop so your I variable will never go past 1... unless it's global and it's changed elsewhere but yea, we need more info.

Comment: What is `I` set to when you call `RunEveryTwoMinutes()`?  I assume it's a global variable?  Also, you've set `RunEveryTwoMinutes()` to run every five seconds.  Did you intend this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, the variable i must be dimensioned as a module or global level variable.

Also, to cancel the OnTime call, you must reference the same start time. I did this by storing the time to a date variable and using it to both start and cancel the OnTime procedure.

```
Dim i as integer

Sub RunEveryTwoMinutes()
Dim t as date
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption = Now
t = now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Application.OnTime t, "RunEveryTwoMinutes"
MsgBox I
I = I + 1

If I = 2 Then
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = " Whant is the Capital of Maharashatra"
UserForm1.OptionButton1.Caption = " Mumbai"
UserForm1.OptionButton2.Caption = " Delhi"
UserForm1.OptionButton3.Caption = " Kolkotta"
UserForm1.OptionButton4.Caption = " Karnatak"
End If


If I = 3 Then
UserForm1.Label1.Caption = " Whant is the Capital of Delphi"
UserForm1.OptionButton1.Caption = " Mumbai"
UserForm1.OptionButton2.Caption = " Delhi"
UserForm1.OptionButton3.Caption = " Kolkotta"
UserForm1.OptionButton4.Caption = " Karnatak"
End If

If I = 4 Then
Application.OnTime t, "RunEveryTwoMinutes", , False

Exit Sub


End If

End Sub
```